# Recommend a web-based narrative RPG

Tags: game-recommendation, play-by-post

[I have played](http://forums.rpgbg.net/viewforum.php?f=77&sid=5fcaf6609b91520b5743b805c44aa55c) forum based RPG before. Posting is something like once per day and nothing is required other than text-writing capacity. I would like to try that again, but in English. It should be a large place, with games starting and stopping all the time, so that I can join quickly. There should be at least some groups that do not require reading a ton of books about some obscure system in order to play.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm giving [roleplayerguild.com](http://roleplayerguild.com) a try and will post impressions timely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first hit on google was [Roleplayer Guild](http://roleplayerguild.com/). It is a large place, with five kinds of games:

- Casual
- More serious
- Serious games
- One-GM-one-player
- Arena

Games start and stop all the time, registration is easy, and anyone can propose a game concept and see if any players turn up. Some games follow rules (I have seen DnD mostly), most are kind of free-form.

On the minus side, the "signatures" of the users, placed under every post, can be distracting - for example a 300x300 pixel flashing manga jumping bunnies. On the other hand, they can be disabled from your profile!

Answer (score 0):

## Rules-ultra-light

Look for "Star Trek Sims," "Pern Weyrs," and various "Battlestars" ... most of these are rules-less shared narrative storywriting. Most without actual game rules.

And there are a bunch of them.

My wife used to do a bunch of play with "Stormfires Weyr."

Most such sites have very simple narrative conventions, usually everything you need being posted on the site.

Some are play by forum, others play by email.

Answer (score 0):

One great narrative rpg online is called "Genesis". One of the best I've ever played. Go to:

[genesismud.org/play](http://genesismud.org/play)

or

[genesismud.org](http://genesismud.org)

This is a great fun game to play, and it never really ends...

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Storium](http://www.storium.com). It has quite a nice system optimized for online collaborative storytelling, and an active community with games in multiple genres.

Answer (score -1):

if you are into superheroes, the atomicthinktank has a pretty good play by post area
you can find it here: http://atomicthinktank.com/viewforum.php?f=20

Comment: Atomic Think Tank is for playing *Mutants & Masterminds*, which isn't mostly-narrative and does require understanding a bunch of M&M books, so -1.

Comment: Dunno how it is at M&M 2e, but at the 3e you need only 1 book. If you just take an archetype you can have read all the rules you need for playing in like 20 minutes.... And contents of the book can be found for free (legally) an the web, thanks to the OGL.